# Compose not show when replace fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, compose-android-vew

I've worked on the `FragmentContainerView` activity with some fragments, in that fragment, I want to use Compose alongside XML using `ComposeView`in the first fragment, but when I try to navigate from the second fragment and back to the first fragment, the component from `ComposeView` was disappeared.

I've set up a fragment with `FragmentContainerView` using the `replace` strategy and I put the fragment inside the list like usual, and I have no idea what happens with this situation.

You can watch in this [video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32610660/215087101-32af4f4c-6791-48e5-9f23-1ffc7c9bceab.mov)

also this is my code

**NavigationActivity.kt**

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkRequest
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import id.derysudrajat.inlinebinding.viewBinding
import id.derysudrajat.library.R
import id.derysudrajat.library.databinding.ActivityNavigationBinding

class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by viewBinding(ActivityNavigationBinding::inflate)

    private val listOfFragment = listOf(FragmentMainNav(), FragmentDetailNav())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnHome.setOnClickListener{
            replace(HOME_NAV)
        }
        binding.btnDetail.setOnClickListener{
            replace(DETAIL_NAV)
        }
        Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.fragmentDetailNav, null)
    }

    private fun replace(nav: String) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(
                binding.fragmentContainerView.id,
                if (nav == HOME_NAV) listOfFragment[0] else listOfFragment[1]
            )
            .commit()
    }

    companion object {
        const val HOME_NAV = "home_nav"
        const val DETAIL_NAV = "detail_nav"
    }
}
```

**FragmentMainNav.kt**

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import id.derysudrajat.inlinebinding.BindingFragment
import id.derysudrajat.inlinebinding.viewBinding
import id.derysudrajat.library.R
import id.derysudrajat.library.databinding.FragmentNavMainBinding

class FragmentMainNav : BindingFragment<FragmentNavMainBinding>() {

    override val binding by viewBinding(FragmentNavMainBinding::inflate)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.textMain.text = "Fragment Main"

        binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent { 
                Text(text = "This is Compose")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**fragment_nav_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment Main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_main" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FragmentDetailNav.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import id.derysudrajat.inlinebinding.BindingFragment
import id.derysudrajat.inlinebinding.viewBinding
import id.derysudrajat.library.databinding.FragmentNavDetailBinding
import id.derysudrajat.library.databinding.FragmentNavMainBinding

class FragmentDetailNav : BindingFragment<FragmentNavDetailBinding>() {

    override val binding by viewBinding(FragmentNavDetailBinding::inflate)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.textDetail.text = "Detail Navigation"
    }
}
```

**fragment_nav_detail.kt**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detail Navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried using different ways like changing `ViewCompositionStrategy` and it still not working, I expected to show `ComposeView` still show when the fragment was replaced and back, btw the compose that I was tried is from compose BOM 2022.10.00 - 2023.01.00 but still disappeared when the fragment was replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could move the `binding.composeView.apply {}` block from **onViewCreated** to **onCreateView** as shown by provided sample in official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments). I've tested it using compose bom 2023.01.00 and plain ViewBinding and it works fine. So the HomeFragment would be like this:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                Text(text = "This is Compose")
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

As additional note, i don't think the `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener()` is necessary and could just be removed.

Comment: Thanks bro, I just realize that I have the wrong handling on managing viewBinding

Answer (score 0):

Please "Dery Sudrajat" what have you realize about the your  handling on managing viewBinding?

Hi have a similar issue, my compose view disappear when the fragment which contains it come from the stack of views!, I mean, my app has the fragment:

A then pass to B.

The fragment A has the compuse, then I return to A from B (onBackPress()), the compuse disappear.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34425782)

Comment: In Android Dev documentation about using compose in view system, they give an example where we must `setContent` in our `ComposeView` is in `onCreateView`, in my view binding library I have put a scenario to `setContent` not in `onCreateView` so it might cause the `ComposeView` disappear, if you want to read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/compose-in-views#compose-in-fragments)